# Activity is not getting generated with the latest ADT - eclipse download

Tags: android

I downloaded the Eclipse ADT Today from this site :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

The zip file was 368 MB around.

Then I followed the exact steps mentioned here :
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

But, when I create an Android Project , activity and layout not are not generating by eclipse.
I searched in the google. Some has advised to go to Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

But for me, it is not allowing me to install as saying latest version is already installed.

Now, I am completely stuck with this issue. Can someone please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: try to download a fresh Eclipse package (on the official Eclipse website). Then install ADT with the "Help > Install new software". I already had some problems with the bundled version !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the latest version of ADT that is available for download. I had the same issue as well. The current work around is to download Eclipse (4.4 is the latest), and install ADT on top of it.